# XHR POST to Philips Hue Bridge

Tags: javascript, cors, same-origin-policy

I'm working on a bridge-like solution to communicate from an HbbTV-application with some Philips Hue lights (correctly with the gateway-hardware).

As the process is moving forward and the system was working, I'm now at the point that I use a plugin for Firefox that simulates a TV with HbbTV. To do so, I start an apache via XAMPP, on this i have my files which are loaded into Firefox.

Since I did that, I can't send any POST-requests to he Philips gateway, what is correct due same origin policy. I have no access to settings on Philips Hue and so my workarround has to be from clientside only.

My actual try looks like this:

```js
  var stringState = "http://" + this.Ip + "/api/" + this.UserId + "/lights/" + this.LightId;
  var httpxml = new XMLHttpRequest();
  
  var valueRequest;
 
  console.log("in GetState:" + this.LightId);
 
   
  httpxml.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (httpxml.readyState  == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
    
    valueRequest = JSON.parse(httpxml.responseText);
    
    console.log(valueRequest);
    console.log(valueRequest.state.on);
     
    that.switchState(valueRequest.state.on);
   }
  }
  
  httpxml.open('GET',stringState,true);

  httpxml.withCredentials = true;
  httpxml.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  
  httpxml.send();
```

I'm pretty new to developing in JavaScript and Web. I hope someone could lead me on the right road, with some advice and maybe a clear example.

Best regards
Adrian

Answer (score 0):

One of the P-s in XAMPP is for PHP. So a workaround you can do is hosting a PHP page right next to your HTML one (and there will not be any issues with CORS), and let it do the job.

Something like

```
<?php
  $ip=$_REQUEST['ip'];
  $user=$_REQUEST['user'];
  $light=$_REQUEST['light'];

  $ch=curl_init("http://".$ip."/api/".$user."/lights/".$light);
  curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
```

This is far from anything safe and nice, but may help to get started. Some trivial clues: variables start with `$`, and `.` is the operator for string concatenation. `$_REQUEST` is an array which gets the url parameters, what you should supply in your modified request (where `xy.php` is the filename of the PHP page):

```
var stringState = "xy.php?ip=" + this.Ip + "&user=" + this.UserId + "&light=" + this.LightId;
```

`curl` is a utility for issuing web requests (you can find it in your XAMPP folders, `xampp\apache\curl.exe`), and it has bindings for PHP. https://curl.haxx.se/. By default it returns whatever your contoller provides, so the JSON should pass-through. Content-type may or may not be an issue, if it does not work, you can try putting a `header("Content-Type: application/json");` right before the `curl_exec` line.

Comment: Excuse me for the long pause, but I was on vacation.
Ok, so I create e new php-file that will send the request, but how do I include that in the html-file?

Comment: @DaPole you have a web server, which can perfectly host multiple files. As you can see I modified the ```stringState``` variable, that is where the ```xy.php``` file is referred from your original file. However originally I mispaired the request variables, hopefully it is correct now.

Comment: Yes that's clear to me. As I understand it correct I have to start the .php with  e.g. AJAX command and the variables ip,user and light should be already loaded due to the StringState construction? No parameters needed? In the end I just collect the response from php and parse it to JSON.
Is there another option to have a workaround for  same origin policy with Javascript, without adding PHP. HbbTV has a very limited freedom what can be used.

Comment: @DaPole yes, the parameters are in the URL - just like they have been in the original case. For getting around the same-origin policy, without the need of an actor in the middle (which does not have to be PHP, [.htaccess](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html) rules, like [redirect](http://www.htaccess-guide.com/redirects/) can probably do the job too, just I do not know them well enough), you can see if you it is possible to host the webpage itself on HbbTV - it does respond to HTTP request already, after all.